# (Delphi XE8 Android) Tmediaplayer, Android buttons wont disappear after clicking on a video

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I am currently porting my adventure game engine to Android using Delphi XE8 and Firemonkey. I wanna make MP4 videoplayback possible. 
I am using a Trectangle with a Tmediaplayercontrol on it. Both are set to align=client.

The game itself runs in borderless fullscreen. Playback of a video works just fine. I make the rectangle visible and load the video. I can also hide the rectangle afterwards.

The problem is : When i tap on the running video the android buttons appear to the right... and won't go away. Even when the playback is finished and the rectangle not visible anymore.

[Android Buttons blocking a part of the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOUYf.jpg)

Also at this point the Back Button doesn't work anymore.

Does anyone know what is going on there and how i can prevent this when the user taps on the video?